# how to add reaction to a specifc user?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've been working on this piece of code:

```py
@client.event
async def lol(message,ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == <user_id>:
        await message.add_reaction('❤️')
    else:
        return
```

I am pretty sure that it is developed correctly, yet I am not getting the desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Have you received any errors? What do you think might be wrong? Please edit your question to be more specific so we can help you more, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that if you check the console, an HTTP error would have been encountered. That's because you directly pasted the emoji in the function parameter. You have to add its unicode value. In your case:

`await message.add_reaction(u'\u2764')`

Comment: It's not necessarily the case, on other devices, they may not support each format of emoji  unicode types and would just display as the "string unicode"

Answer (score 0):

You are using an event decorator rather than a command, unless you were trying to detect if the user reacted, but its still completely off. What it looks like, the command that is called will send a message and the bot will react to it.

```
@client.command()
async def lol(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, lol")
    await message.add_reaction('')
```

If you then want to detect if the user had reacted to the emoji, you can use a event, but an on_reaction_add:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

        if reaction.emoji == '':
            await user.send("Lol")
```

Comment: change these to what ever you had or want to say. Check my answer